# Adicionar atalho para comando no jupyter notebook

Tags: ipython-notebook

Olá, existe uma forma de adicionar uma tecla de atalho para o comando:

-restart kernel & clean output

Sem precisar executar o código toda vez que abrir o jupyter notebook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existe sim. Dentro de um notebook, na aba **help** procure por Edit keyboard Shortcuts, será aberto um pop-up como na imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

e haverá a linha `restart kernel and clear output`, então basta colocar suas tecla de atalho, por exemplo `Shift-r`